# Wpf control is not visible when application is doing some task, it is apperaring after the task is completed

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

i am working on winform application , one screen of my application i am using a wpf user control . i am setting visiblity of that WPF user control through binding.
there is no threading in my application, i want that as soon as set the visiblility of user control it should effect in UI,but is not happening like that.

i am able to see my WPF user control after the screen is loaded fully.

Hi,

i am working on winform application , one screen of my application i am using a wpf user control . i am setting visiblity of that WPF user control through binding.
there is no threading in my application, i want that as soon as set the visiblility of user control it should effect in UI,but is not happening like that.

i am able to see my WPF user control after the screen is loaded fully.

my code somewhat look like this

```
void Dosomething()
{
IsUserControlEnabled=true;//here the UI should reflect but not happening

//some time taking code assume 4-8 sec

IsUserControlEnabled=false;

}

What I have tried:

void Dosomething()
{
IsUserControlEnabled=true;//here the UI should reflect but not happening

//some time taking code assume 4-8 sec

// if aim not setting IsUserControlEnabled=false then i am able to see in my UI but i want that in this method only it should appear an disappear

}
```

i am assuming my problem is releated to below link
[my problem is somewhat releated to this link](http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.in/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class which you are binding to is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and that you're raising a PropertyChanged event in the get accessor of your IsUserControlEnabled property. Your UserControl listens for PropertyChanged events to know when to update the control's visual properties, and if it doesn't get them it won't know to update itself.